Executing Stored Procedures across Different Databases
I have a staging database [StageDB] and a production database [ProdDB] where data is initially imported from an API into the [StageDB] and then the data inserted or updated into the ProdDB.
I have a Windows authenticated Login to the instance named [User1], which has a Public Server Role and User Mapping to [StageDB] and [ProdDB] but no Memberships.
There is stored procedure on [ProdDB] named proc_update_documents.
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_update_documents]
AS

UPDATE [ProdDB].[dbo].[tbl_documents]
    SET
        [last_name] = D.[last_name],
        [first_name] = D.[first_name],
        [category] = D.[category]
FROM
        [StageDB].[dbo].[tbl_documents] D
WHERE
        D.[document_id] = [ProdDB].[dbo].[tbl_documents].[document_id];

INSERT INTO [ProdDB].[dbo].[tbl_documents]
(
    [document_id],
    [last_name],
    [first_name],
    [category]
)

SELECT
    [document_id],
    [last_name],
    [first_name],
    [category]
FROM
    [StageDB].[dbo].[tbl_documents] D
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS(SELECT [document_id] FROM [ProdDB].[dbo].[tbl_documents] X WHERE D.[document_id] = X.[document_id])

I then have a stored procedure in [StageDB] named proc_ProdDB_update_documents
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_ProdDB_update_documents]
AS

EXEC [ProdDB].[dbo].[proc_update_documents]

User1 has been granted EXECUTE permission on both stored procedures
USE [ProdDB]
GO
GRANT EXEC ON [dbo].[proc_update_documents] TO [User1];
GO

USE [StageDB]
GO
GRANT EXEC ON [dbo].[proc_ProdDB_update_documents] TO [User1];
GO

However, when I execute the stored procedure proc_ProdDB_update_documents from StageDB I get SELECT permission errors although User1 has EXECUTE permissions on the stored procedures.
USE [StageDB]
Go

EXEC [dbo].[proc_ProdDB_update_documents]


Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Procedure
ProdDB.dbo.proc_update_documents, Line 4 [Batch Start Line 2] The
SELECT permission was denied on the object 'tbl_documents', database
'StageDB', schema 'dbo'.
Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Procedure
ProdDB.dbo.proc_update_documents, Line 23 [Batch Start Line 2] The
SELECT permission was denied on the object 'tbl_documents', database
'StageDB', schema 'dbo'.
Completion time: 2024-05-01T15:30:14.6407168+01:00

I do not want the user User1 to have SELECT permissions to the underlying tables, but only EXECUTE permissions to the stored procedures. If I give User1 SELECT permissions on StageDB.tbl_Documents then store procedures work OK, but I am hoping not to do that...

Database Chaining will stop as soon as you have a cross database query. You'll need to either: 1. CREATE a USER in the other database and give them SELECT permissions. 2. Enable cross database chaining and ensure everything has the same owner (this comes with a lot of security implications you need to consider first). 3. Sign the procedure and give the CERTIFICATE in the target database the needed permissions. - There are plenty on tutorials and existing questions about all of these.

Examples based on Thom A's comment.

Easy to understand but User1 has access to the tables in ProdDB.

SET ANSI_NULLS, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
GO
USE StageDB;
GO
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.proc_update_documents
AS
SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

UPDATE P
SET last_name = S.last_name
    ,first_name = S.first_name
    ,category = S.category
FROM ProdDB.dbo.tbl_documents P
    JOIN dbo.tbl_documents S
        ON P.document_id = S.document_id;

INSERT INTO ProdDB.dbo.tbl_documents(document_id, last_name, first_name, category)
SELECT S.document_id, S.last_name, S.first_name, S.category
FROM dbo.tbl_documents S
    LEFT JOIN ProdDB.dbo.tbl_documents P
        ON S.document_id = P.document_id
WHERE P.document_id IS NULL;

GO
GRANT EXEC ON dbo.proc_update_documents TO User1;
GO
USE ProdDB;
GO
GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON dbo.tbl_documents(document_id, last_name, first_name, category) TO User1;
GRANT UPDATE ON dbo.tbl_documents(last_name, first_name, category) TO User1;
GO
/*
USE StageDB;
GO
EXEC dbo.proc_update_documents
GO
*/


I would avoid cross database ownership chaining.
Certificate signing based on Erland Sommarskog's paper.
It looks complicated but you can write your own helper functions. User1 does not have access to the tables in ProdDB.

USE StageDB;
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
GO
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.proc_update_documents
AS
SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;
UPDATE P
SET last_name = S.last_name
    ,first_name = S.first_name
    ,category = S.category
FROM ProdDB.dbo.tbl_documents P
    JOIN dbo.tbl_documents S
        ON P.document_id = S.document_id;
INSERT INTO ProdDB.dbo.tbl_documents(document_id, last_name, first_name, category)
SELECT S.document_id, S.last_name, S.first_name, S.category
FROM dbo.tbl_documents S
    LEFT JOIN ProdDB.dbo.tbl_documents P
        ON S.document_id = P.document_id
WHERE P.document_id IS NULL;
GO
IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM sys.crypt_properties P
        JOIN sys.certificates C
            ON P.thumbprint = P.thumbprint
    WHERE OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(P.major_id) = N'dbo'
        AND OBJECT_NAME(P.major_id) = N'proc_update_documents'
        AND C.[name] = N'dbo_proc_update_documents$Cert'
)
DROP SIGNATURE FROM dbo.proc_update_documents BY CERTIFICATE dbo_proc_update_documents$Cert;
IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM sys.certificates
    WHERE [name] = N'dbo_proc_update_documents$Cert'
)
DROP CERTIFICATE dbo_proc_update_documents$Cert;
GO
DECLARE @password nchar(37) = convert(nchar(36), newid()) + 'a'
    ,@SQL nvarchar(MAX);
SET @SQL = CONCAT
(
N'CREATE CERTIFICATE dbo_proc_update_documents$Cert
ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD =  N''', @password, N'''
WITH SUBJECT = ''"Cert for dbo_proc_update_documents"'';'
);
EXEC (@SQL);
SET @SQL = CONCAT
(
N'ADD SIGNATURE TO dbo.proc_update_documents BY CERTIFICATE dbo_proc_update_documents$Cert
WITH PASSWORD = N''', @password, N''';'
);
EXEC (@SQL);
ALTER CERTIFICATE dbo_proc_update_documents$Cert REMOVE PRIVATE KEY;
GO
DECLARE @public_key varbinary(MAX) = CERTENCODED(CERT_ID(N'dbo_proc_update_documents$Cert'))
    ,@SQL nvarchar(MAX);
USE ProdDB;
DROP USER IF EXISTS dbo_proc_update_documents$CertUser;
IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM sys.certificates
    WHERE [name] = N'dbo_proc_update_documents$Cert'
)
DROP CERTIFICATE dbo_proc_update_documents$Cert;
SET @SQL = CONCAT
(
N'CREATE CERTIFICATE dbo_proc_update_documents$Cert
FROM BINARY = ', CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), @public_key, 1), N';'
);
EXEC (@SQL);
GO
CREATE USER dbo_proc_update_documents$CertUser FROM CERTIFICATE dbo_proc_update_documents$Cert;
REVOKE SELECT, INSERT ON dbo.tbl_documents(document_id, last_name, first_name, category) FROM User1;
REVOKE UPDATE ON dbo.tbl_documents(last_name, first_name, category) FROM User1;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON dbo.tbl_documents(document_id, last_name, first_name, category) TO dbo_proc_update_documents$CertUser;
GRANT UPDATE ON dbo.tbl_documents(last_name, first_name, category) TO dbo_proc_update_documents$CertUser;
GO
/*
USE StageDB;
GO
EXEC dbo.proc_update_documents
GO
*/

